# Idea need at android AlertDialogue box

Tags: android

I am learning Android and I am facing one issue while creating a dialogue box. I want to System.exit(0) on clicking on negative button. But I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Below is my code:

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Check Below..")
                    .setMessage("No Internet Connection")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Go Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            finish();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Exit", null).show();


}
```

Comment: Whats the error/problem?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I dont know how to do it

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? What do yo want on positive button click and on negative button click? Also I remember asking you not to use `System.exit(0)` couple days ago. Its a bad idea.

Comment: On clicking positive button it will call finish() and on negative button it should call System.exit(0);

Comment: Well if you really have to use it then, see my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Check Below..")
                .setMessage("No Internet Connection")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Go Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        finish();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                }).show();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have one doubt. Why we need to append .show() in negative button but not in positive button ? plz

Comment: You are not appending `show()` in negative button. You are appending it in `Builder`. See it continues using dot operator.

Answer (score 4):

If do you want to kill the activity when the negative button is clicked, you simply have to write:

```
ClassName.this.finish();
```